# easy trigger to rank dates and insert rank - apex - salesforce

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I'm new to Salesforce and do not have any coding experience.  I've been so impressed with SF that I'm now on a mission to learn APEX.  In order to learn APEX, I need to learn java.  So after struggling to create triggers - and to make since of code examples out there - I signed up for an intro java CS class through iTunesU (free - from Stanford).

I could be a hero with a friend at work if I can make a simple trigger work though.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

- A workflow rule fills out a formula field with DATETIME data on a contact once a picklist value is saved on the contact record.
- This picklist will only show for one day b/c of a promo at work.
- How can I design a trigger to rank order the DATETIME field (earliest time = 1, next time = 2, etc.) and insert the rank into another SF a Field on the same contact?
- I will not have to worry about any bulk loading issues.  Two users could possibly hit save at the same time on a contact.  I know I will need a test case to get this into production but I will worry about that later!

I found this which I think is a good start?

[How to sort list items for Date field value (Apex, Salesforce)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816899/how-to-sort-list-items-for-date-field-value-apex-salesforce)

Here is a another example that deals with sorting a list by alphabetical order: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9418463/1373598

Answer (score 2):

It's great that you're on a mission to learn Apex! You don't really need to know Java, though. Some general programming concepts (variables, datatypes, loops, methods/functions, etc) would be enough.

It seems like you know a bit about [Triggers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_triggers.htm) already. As you probably know, they execute code based on certain conditions. [Trigger Context Variables](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) are very important when you're developing with them; these provide data on the record(s) that the Trigger action is being performed on. I would read that documentation thoroughly first. The examples provided are really helpful.

When working with triggers, it's also important to [understand debug logs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm) and how to [check them](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/code_monitoring_debug_logs.htm). You can log anything using the [`System.debug();`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm) method.

After you have the basics of a Trigger in place, you can begin to add sorting logic to it. Data in [Lists](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=langCon_apex_collections_lists.htm|StartTopic=Content%2FlangCon_apex_collections_lists.htm|SkinName=webhelp) (if the List type is a [primitive data type](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#langCon_apex_primitives.htm)) can be sorted by calling the `List.sort();` method, but you would have to keep track of what sObject the data (date) is on. You may need to write your own sort method using a [sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) (bubble sort or insertion sort are a couple that I have used before) or use [some sorting code that has already been developed](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/A-gift-for-you-Sorting-a-List-lt-sObject-gt/td-p/107833).

I know that's a lot of information, but it should get you started; good luck!

Comment: Thank you, your post was very helpful!  I am having issues getting the sort to work.                                                  trigger rank on Contact (before insert, before update) {

List<Contact> contacts = new list<Contact>();

for (Contact rank : Trigger.new) {
if(rank.Date_Time_Of_Call__c != null)
contacts.sort(); // I also tried contacts.sort(Date_Time_Of_Call__c)
}}                                                                         // I wasn't able to find any basis sorting examples out there.

Comment: Sorting only works for primitive data types (until the Summer '12 release). So, `List<DateTime> dt = new List<DateTime>(); dt.sort();` would work after adding DateTime values to the List, but `List<Contact> c = new List<Contact>(); c.sort();` would not.